# Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(dryRun)

Tags: angular, macos, angular-cli

I installed latest Angular 6.0.4 in MAC, when I enter in terminal:

```
ng new happiness
```

display:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"dryRun":false,"version":"6.0.4","skipGit":false,"skipInstall":false,"linkCli":false,"commit":true,"newProjectRoot":"projects","inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,"routing":false,"prefix":"app","style":"css","skipTests":false} Errors:Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(dryRun).
```

Anyone can tell me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I installed angular with : npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Angular 6.0.5 version

```
npm update
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.5
ng new --name my-app
```

Another thread is same:
[Issue while ng new app-name angular cli 6.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521215/issue-while-ng-new-app-name-angular-cli-6-0-4/50521669#50521669)

Comment: It's OK. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Can you try following:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

there was an issue. You can find [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10312).

Comment: This solved my problem when I was seeing `Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(es5BrowserSupport)`. Upgrading my Angular CLI to v10 wasn't helping either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was using angular cli version 6.0.4, and it seems like there is some issue with the version. I uninstalled 6.0.4 and installed 6.0.2, and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this issue with the version 6.0.4 and unfortunately it is still (25-05-2.18 10:59 AM IST) open in [github-#11006](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11006). So uninstall angular cli and install 6.0.3. Another issue I have found that sh1 checksum error, it will occur when installing new nodejs.
(in windows machine)
to install new cli

```
 1. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
 2. npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.3
 3. npm cache verify
```

if you are getting Sha1 and sha512 checksum error then,

```
If already node installed and you are planning to install new node and new 
cli then uninstall old nodejs then delete the cache manually before 
installing new nodejs (C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm & C:\Users\ 
<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm)
```

It worked for me

Comment: Yes, It is 6.0.4 problem.change to 6.0.3, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the new **6.0.5** version fixed this issue
[more info](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11006)

Unfortunately, due to some issue found after doing the 6.0.4 release, we were forced to rollback. This release is the same as 6.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the new 6+ version fixed this issue in Mac when we create an angular project after update Angular CLI version.

So run this command:

```
npm i @schematics/angular@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying you need to remove the "dryRun" key from the json structure. Add the `--dry-run` flag to your cli command instead (if you want it).