# Angular 6 Library assets not included in lib after build

Tags: angular

I have recently created an Angular library (ng new library) and had an issue after building it with the `ng build --prod`. My assets folder did not get copied to the dist folder and I can no longer reference my file. When I tried including the `assets` script in my `angular.json` I got an error `- Schema validation failed` with the following errors:

> Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(assets).

Is there a way of including assets in an Angular library? Please help

Comment: Another thread have same issue: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521032/data-path-should-not-have-additional-propertiesdryrun

Comment: That is not related

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Angular CLI 6.1.3. Change your assets part in your angular.json file :

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/web.config",
  "src/assets"
],
```

It works even if you don't have a web.config file.

Comment: hey thanks @veben I see assets array got copied to my library package.json, the only problem I have is that I get a 404 error

Comment: I receive a "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory" on "src/assets".

Answer (score 0):

Now, [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) released a new version that allows you to include the assets along with the build files:

**You can copy these assets by using the assets option.**

```
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "assets": [
      "CHANGELOG.md",
      "./styles/**/*.theme.scss"
    ],
    "lib": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

More information here: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md