# Angular 9 how to include fonts during library build

Tags: assets, angular-library, angular-builder

I´m trying to use my angular library for an external project.
I would like this project can use directly fonts from my library.
I noticed the folder `projects/my-library/src/lib/styles/fonts` is not included when I build my library.

I tried to follow answers of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289213/angular-6-library-assets-not-included-in-lib-after-build) without success.
I tried this :

**ng-package.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/my-library",
  "assets": [
    "./src/lib/styles/fonts/**"
  ],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "styleIncludePaths": ["node_modules", "src/lib/styles"]
  }
}
```

In this case, I have a directory `src/...` created in `dist/my-library` and I got this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'path/to/dist/my-library/src/lib/styles/fonts'

or

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/my-library",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "styleIncludePaths": ["node_modules", "src/lib/styles"],
    "cssUrl": "inline"
  }
}
```

I got this error :

> WARNING: postcss-url: ... Can't read file 'path/to/font.eot'

Someone knows the way to properly include fonts or others assets for library build like inside `dist/my-library/lib/styles/fonts` ?