# Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(skipTests)

Tags: angular

I have a brand new project built using angular v12.0. When i run command  `ng g m home` I gets the following error:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"skipTests":true,"path":"src/app/pages","name":"home","project":"HallesWeb"}
Errors:

  Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(skipTests).
```

While creating this project using `ng new` I used `--skip-tests` flag to true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(dryRun)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521032/data-path-should-not-have-additional-propertiesdryrun)

Comment: I don't want to update my CLI or anything. What i want is to solve the SCHEMATIC INPUT ISSUE within the current version.